# Good examples of implementing forms with client/server side validation in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

While Django makes it very easy to create simple HTML forms, I wonder if anyone could suggest good open-source Django projects with examples for implementing "modern-looking" forms with additional elements such as:

1. [disqus registration form](https://disqus.com/admin/register/)
2. [twitter registration form](https://twitter.com/signup)

I have looked at several projects:

1. [django-uni-form](https://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form)
2. [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/) (seems to be a successor for previous one)
3. [django-ajax-forms](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-forms/)

but I can't seem to find any good examples to learn from.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "Poll" questions are considered to be "not constructive" on SO (unfortunately I'm out of close votes, so I can't vote to close it as that). See the [questions not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) section of the FAQ.

Comment: @agf Don't see poll question here.

Comment: @DrTyrsa He wants a list of examples. There is no right answer, or even best answer. That's a poll. Hundreds of old questions like from before that rule was in place have been closed / deleted. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127661/how-can-i-post-an-answer-with-many-links-or-earn-that-privilege-without-being-a the MSO question that caused it.

Comment: No app is going to give you 'modern looking forms'. It's combination of javascript, good design and normal django Forms/ModelForms

Comment: @agf, how is it different (in concept) from highly-rated questions like this one (among many others?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540482/well-designed-django-example-code-to-learn-from

Comment: @MikeAr Those are slowly getting closed / locked / deleted as the mods notice them. The rules weren't well defined back then. People with over 10k rep can see many, many deleted questions just like that.

Comment: @agf Thanks for the explanation. That's too bad, as a relative newbie in Django I do find a lot of answers for questions like that very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It integrates very well with django-crispy-forms and will let you produce very clean, modern looking forms quite easily, with very little work on the client side.

It won't help you out with Ajax functionality, but will handle look and feel quite nicely.